# Intercepting jQuery mobile page-flow, parse JSON before page change

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, cordova, jquery-mobile

A normal page-flow with jQuery mobile looks somewhat like this:

> 1. Starts on static page (foo.html)
> 2. Clicks link
> 3. End up on another static page (bar.html)

I need to alter this behavior. I'm looking for something like this instead:

> 1. Starts on static page (foo.html)
> 2. Clicks link
> 3. Gathers json from server (based on i.e  a how a form looks)
> 4. Renders the other page (bar.html) based on the data gathered from the previous step

Normally, I'd simply do this via a PHP-script with POST/GET. However, the project is a PhoneGap project, so this isn't an alternative.

One possible solution is if I somehow can point the first page's form to the second one, hence the second one is able to pick up the first page's post-parameters. This feels quite hackish, though. I'd also prefer to parse the second page before showing it, which makes even more complicated.

How can I achieve this behavior? Or rather; how to pass data between pages?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$.mobile.changePage("newPage.html", {data:{param1:'value1'}});
```

and then on newPage.html

```
var url = $.url(document.location);
var param1 = url.param("param1");
```

Does this help you?

Comment: This is exactly what I'm looking for. However, the `document.location` returns the URL of the first page; not the URL of the page which I just changed to (.. which has the data in the `location.search` property). I'm using `JQM 1.1.1` if that matters.

Answer (score 1):

There are also `pagebeforechange` and `pagebeforeshow` events which may help you achieve what you want.

http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/api/events.html